# Multiple file project & Function in C++

Tags: c++, function, header-files

I am trying to practice the multiple file project (creating .cpp files and also .h files) and functions together.I have some functions for different kinds of shapes which is in different .cpp files and a .h file (my Functions.h) with the prototypes of those functions. I created another .cpp file (tools.cpp) where I have all bunch of functions (such as- getInt, getFloat, getBool, getBoundedInt, getWidth etc) so that I can also use that one in my other projects as well and also for that tools.cpp file. I have tools.h file with the prototypes. 
Now, I want to make another function (allFunctionController) which will handle all these different kinds of function (like- taking user input, checking input valid or invalid, help function for user, call the shape functions etc). And, there would be another function to allow user to repeat all these things and my main function will only call this one. The screenshot that I provided would be more clear to understand.

**[screenshot]**

[image]

tools.cpp :-

```
// Tools.cpp

#include"Tools.h"
#include<string>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

namespace tools
{
    int width( int value )
    {
        bool isNegative = value < 0;
        int spaceForSign;
        if ( isNegative )
        {
            spaceForSign = 1;
            value = -value;
        }
        else
            spaceForSign = 0;

        int digitCount = 0;
        int digits = value;
        do
        {
            // pull one digit off and count it;
            ++digitCount;

            // if I wanted to look at the digit before throwing away:
            int digit = digits % 10;

            digits = digits / 10; // remove one digit
        } while  ( digits > 0 );

        return digitCount;
    }

    char getChar(string prompt)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            char userInput;
            cout << prompt;
            cin >> userInput;
            cin.ignore(999,'\n');
            if ( !cin.fail() ) return userInput;
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(999,'\n');
            cout << "try again" << endl;
        }
    }

    int getInt(string prompt)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            int userInput;
            cout << prompt;
            cin >> userInput;
            cin.ignore(999,'\n');
            if ( !cin.fail() ) return userInput;
            cout << "input failure, try again";
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(999,'\n');
        }
    }

    int getBoundedInt( string prompt, int lowBound, int highBound )
    {
        while (true)
        {
            int userInput = getInt(prompt);
            if ( lowBound <= userInput && userInput <= highBound )
                return userInput;
            cout << "must be in range " << lowBound << " to "
                << highBound << ", try again" << endl;
        }
    }

    float getFloat(string prompt)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            float userInput;
            cout << prompt;
            cin >> userInput;
            cin.ignore(999,'\n');
            if ( !cin.fail() ) return userInput;
            cout << "input failure, try again";
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(999,'\n');
        }
    }

    string getString(string prompt)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            string userInput;
            cout << prompt;
            cin >> userInput;
            cin.ignore(999,'\n');
            if ( !cin.fail() ) return userInput;
            cout << "input failure, try again";
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(999,'\n');
        }
    }

    string getLine(string prompt)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            string userInput;
            cout << prompt;
            getline(cin, userInput);
            if ( !cin.fail() ) return userInput;
            cout << "input failure, try again";
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(999,'\n'); // whatever caused fail
        }
    }

    bool isLowerCase( char c )
    {
        return 'a' <= c && c <= 'z';
    }

    bool isUpperCase( char c )
    {
        return 'A' <= c && c <= 'Z';
    }

    bool isLetter( char c )
    {
        return isLowerCase(c) || isUpperCase(c);
    }

    char getLetter(string prompt)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            char userInput = getChar(prompt);
            if ( isLetter(userInput) )
                return userInput;
            cout << "letters only, please" << endl;
        }
    }

    bool getBool(string prompt)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            switch ( getChar(prompt) )
            {
            case 'y': case 'Y': return true;
            case 'n': case 'N': return false;
            }
            cout << "y or n please" << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

tools.h:-

```
// Tools.h

#ifndef TOOLS_LOCK
#define TOOLS_LOCK

#include<string>

namespace tools
{
    int getInt(std::string prompt);
    int width( int value );
    char getChar(std::string prompt);
    int getInt(std::string prompt);
    int getBoundedInt( std::string prompt, int lowBound, int highBound );
    float getFloat(std::string prompt);
    std::string getString(std::string prompt);
    std::string getLine(std::string prompt);
    bool isLowerCase( char c );
    bool isUpperCase( char c );
    bool isLetter( char c );
    char getLetter(std::string prompt);
    bool getBool(std::string prompt);
}

#endif
```

My functions.h:-

```
// My functions.h

namespace myFunctions
{
    void allFunctionController ();
    void solidRectangle (int size);
    void hollowRectangle (int userChoiceOfSize);
    void solidTriangleFacingNorthEast (int size);
    void hollowTriangleFacingNorthEast (int size);
    void solidTriangleFacingSouthWest (int size);
    void hollowTriangleFacingSouthWest (int size);
}
```

I am only adding here the hollow and solid rectangle code. But there are more shape function in my project.

hollowRectangle.cpp:-

```
#include"My functions.h"
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

namespace myFunctions
{
    void hollowRectangle (int size)
    {
        int row, column;

        for (row = 1; row <= size; row++)
        {
            if (row > 1 && row < size)
            {
                cout << "*";
                for (column = 2; column < size; column++)
                {
                    cout << ' ';
                }
                cout << "*";
            }
            else 
            {
                for (column = 1; column <= size; column++)
                {
                    cout << "*";
                }
            }
        }
            cout << endl;

        cout << endl;
        cout << "Please press enter to finish...";
        cin.ignore(999,'\n');
        return;
    }
}
```

solidRectangle.cpp:-

```
// Program for the solid rectangle

#include"My functions.h"
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

namespace myFunctions 
{
    int solidRectangle (int size)
    {
        int row, column;

        for (row = 1; row <= size; row++)
        {
            for (column = 1; column <= size; column++)
            {
                cout << "*";
            }
            cout << endl;
        }

        cout << endl;
        cout << "Please press enter to finish...";
        cin.ignore(999,'\n');
        return 0;
    }
}
```

allFunctionController:- I screwed up here.

```
// This function will control all other functions. 

#include"My functions.h"
#include"Tools.h"
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

void allFunctionController ()
{
    using namespace tools;
    {
        int size = getBoundedInt ("Please enter the size", 1, 75);

    }
}

using namespace myFunctions;
{
void getHelp ()
{
    int size,userInput;
    cin >> userInput;
    switch (userInput)
    {
    case 1: 
        solidRectangle (size);
    }
}
}
```

I want to know how to handle all these header files and use the function in my  allFunctionController function.
I didn't write my main function yet. Please let me know if there is anything wrong in my posting either code or attachment. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you trying to ask exactly?

Comment: I am asking how my allFunctionController should look like to run the program correctly?

Comment: include your header file and just call the functions you have written (just like for built-in header files) - if that's what you are wondering about

Comment: One helpful thing to realize and understand is, #include in C++ is nothing more than copy-paste of the contents of .h file. There is no hidden magic etc. This is why you for example need include guard defines.